# Subquery on PRAGMA table_info()

Tags: php, sqlite, subquery

```
$tbl = 'brand';
$sth = self::$db->prepare('PRAGMA table_info(SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = ? LIMIT 1)');
$sth->execute(array($tbl));
$obj = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$sth->closeCursor();
return $obj;
```

This script returns `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`. I assume the error is made by Syntax Error in the statement, while the `brand` table is exist within the database.

My question is, is there another way to perform such statement in SQLite3?
I want to get the table info of a given table name from an input by user.

Answer (score 0):

Just use string concatenation to create and execute the following SQL:

PRAGMA table_info(brand)

Don't use a sub query to get the table name.

Comment: table name and column name are not allowed to be an argument

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The argument to table_info cannot be a string literal so my previous answer was incorrect. I've corrected my answer now.

Comment: ya, but the given table name is an input from user

Comment: If you need to validate the table name you'll need to perform a separate query to sqlite_master first.